# How to hide header on a specific screen of a TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a Tab Navigator :

```js
const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Home',  
    },
},
OtherPage: {
    screen: OtherPage,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'NoHeader!',
    },
},
Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Profile',
    }
},
},
{
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'black',
        style: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        },
    }
});

TabNav.navigationOptions = {
title: 'Header Title',
headerRight: (
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('Rules')}
    >
        <Icon style={{ paddingRight: 10 }} name="ios-document" > </Icon>
    </TouchableOpacity>
),
headerLeft: null,
}
export default TabNav;
```

I would like to hide the header in the OtherPage, but I need it in my Home and Profile page.

I tried to set header:null in the navigationOptions, but It doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this ? 
Or maybe to specify like in a stack navigator headerMode:'screen' ?

**EDIT**

I tried to add navigationOtions in each TabNavigator screen, and set it to null in my OtherPage like so :

```
const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
            <Icon
                name={focused ? 'ios-list' : 'ios-list-outline'}
                size={35}
                style={{ color: tintColor }}
            />
        ),
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('Rules')}
            >
                <Icon style={{ paddingRight: 10 }} name="ios-document" > </Icon>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerLeft: null,
    },
},
OtherPage: {
    screen: OtherPage,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'NoHeader!',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
            <Icon
                name={focused ? 'ios-flash' : 'ios-flash-outline'}
                size={35}
                style={{ color: tintColor }}
            />
        ),
        header:null
    },
},
Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Profile',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
            <Icon
                name={focused ? 'ios-person' : 'ios-person-outline'}
                size={35}
                style={{ color: tintColor }}
            />
        ),
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('Rules')}
            >
                <Icon style={{ paddingRight: 10 }} name="ios-document" > </Icon>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerLeft: null,
    }
},
```

But it's also not working, when I do this i have a default header (no title, no button on right, ...) on every tabs (even my OtherPage).

Comment: Did you find an answer for your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining navigationOtions for TabNav, add navigationOtions in each TabNavigator screen, then setting header:null in otherPage will work. for example

```js
const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home',

      headerRight: ( <
        TouchableOpacity onPress = {
          () => NavigationService.navigate('Rules')
        } >
        <
        Icon style = {
          {
            paddingRight: 10
          }
        }
        name = "ios-document" > < /Icon> < /
        TouchableOpacity >
      ),
      headerLeft: null,
    },
  },
  OtherPage: {
    screen: OtherPage,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'NoHeader!',
      header: null
    },
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Profile"
      headerRight: ( <
        TouchableOpacity onPress = {
          () => NavigationService.navigate('Rules')
        } >
        <
        Icon style = {
          {
            paddingRight: 10
          }
        }
        name = "ios-document" > < /Icon> < /
        TouchableOpacity >
      ),
      headerLeft: null,
    }
  },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'black',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Not working for me, Now I have the same default header in my 3 tabs, In Home and Profile page the header is not customized, and in my OtherPage header still showing. My version of react navigation is 2.0.2

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick!

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: FeedStack,
  Profile: ProfileStack,
});

TabNavigator.navigationOptions = {
  // Hide the header from AppNavigator stack
  header: null,
};
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html